# How (if it is possible) can a custom field be added to a paginated response in Django / REST?

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a view like the following:

```
class FooView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    pagination_class = FooPagination
```

Which returns a typical paginated response such as:

```
{
     "count":2,
     "next":null,
     "previous":null,
     "results":[
      {
          "id":1,"name":"Josh"
       },
      {
          "id":2,"name":"Vicky"
      }]
}
```

How (if it is possible) can a custom field be added to this response so the result is as follows?

```
{
    "count":2,
    "next":null,
    "previous":null,
    "custom":"some value",
    "results":[
    {
         "id":1,"name":"Josh"
     },
     {
         "id":2,"name":"Vicky"
      }]
}
```

Assuming that "some value" is calculated in an appropriate method and stored, such as:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.custom = get_custom_value(self)
    # etc...
```

Comment: Custom field will be added in the `FooSerializer` class. The fields are there in the serializer will be displayed. Pagination will only deal with number of result to page. This deal with the custom fields also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **override the `get_paginated_response()`** in `FooPagination` class to add a custom field in your response.

You can do something like:

```
class FooPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('custom': some_value), # add the 'custom' field  
            ('results', data),            
        ]))
```

Comment: This method does the job, I used "return Response(resp_dict)", where resp_dict is a regular Python dictionary.

Comment: Yes, you can use that. I had used `OrderedDict` to preserve the order in case you need it.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible solution is add custom fields to your response, don't need override Pagination class

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(YourClass, self).list(request, args, kwargs)
        # Add data to response.data Example for your object:
        response.data['custom_fields'] = 10 # Or wherever you get this values from
        return response
```

Comment: this is the cleanest way to add to response without modifying the entire set of results just for one custom value, I hope I could do 10 ups to give them all to you sir

Answer (score 0):

In a modified version of Rahul Gupta's answer, we can update the returned data from get_paginated_response function and just add a custom field to OrderedDict.
This will keep the super class method intact and in future if any new changes happen to super method it will not affect

```
class CustomFieldPageNumberPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
       def get_paginated_response(self, data):
           paginated_response = super(CustomFieldPageNumberPagination, self).get_paginated_response(data=data)
           paginated_response.data['custom_field']=<custom_field_value>
           return paginated_response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class LimitOffsetPagination(_LimitOffsetPagination):


    def get_paginated_response(self, data, **kwargs):
    return Response(
        OrderedDict(
            [
                ("count", self.count),
                ("next", self.get_next_offset()),
                ("previous", self.get_previous_link()),
                ("data", data),
            ] + [(key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items()]
        ) 
        
    )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).